# Parametric curve is always in front of Surface

Tags: python, animation, math, manim

I am trying to build an animation of a [Dehn twist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dehn_twist) in a torus in Manim. My goal is to get something that looks like this:

[image: Dehn twist in Mathematica]

I managed to parametrize the curve and surface correctly in Manim.

[image: Dehn twist in Manim]

As you can see, the portion of the parametric curves that should be hidden are entirely visible, which makes the picture harder to understand. How can I make the visualization show whether the curve is in front of or behind the surface?

I have looked at the [Manim community](https://docs.manim.community/en/stable/) documentation but could not find anything on this topic.

Here is code reproducing the image above:

```py
from manim import *

class DehnTwist(ThreeDScene):
    def torus_coordinates(self, u, v, t=0):
        return np.array([np.cos(u), np.sin(u), 0]) + 1/2 * (t * abs(np.sin(u/2)) + 1 - t) * np.array([np.cos(u)* np.cos(v), np.sin(u)*np.cos(v), np.sin(v)])
    def cycle_a_twisted_coordinates(self, u, t=0):
        return np.array([np.cos(u), -np.sin(u),0]) + 1/2*(t*abs(np.sin(u/2))+1-t)*np.array([np.sin(u)*np.cos(u),-np.sin(u)*np.sin(u), np.cos(u)])
    
    def cycle_a_twisted(self, t, axes):
        return ParametricFunction(
            lambda u: axes.c2p(*self.cycle_a_twisted_coordinates(u,t)),
            t_range=[0,TAU],
            color=PURE_RED
        )
    def torus(self, t, axes):
        return Surface(
            lambda u, v: axes.c2p(*self.torus_coordinates(u, v, t)),
            u_range=[0, TAU],
            v_range=[0, TAU],
            fill_opacity=0.6,
            resolution=20,
        )
    
    def construct(self):
        axes = ThreeDAxes(x_range=[-4,4], x_length=8)
        
        torus = self.torus(0, axes)
        cycle_a_twisted = self.cycle_a_twisted(0, axes)
        
        self.set_camera_orientation(theta=-30 * DEGREES, phi=60 * DEGREES)
        self.camera.set_zoom(2)
        
        self.add(cycle_a_twisted,torus)
```

**EDIT:**
I have updated my code with regards to @A-_-S 's answer, and also simplified the curve for lisibility.

```py
from manim import *

class DehnTwist(ThreeDScene):
    def torus_coordinates(self, u, v):
        return np.array([np.cos(u), np.sin(u), 0]) + 1/2 * np.array([np.cos(u)* np.cos(v), np.sin(u)*np.cos(v), np.sin(v)])
    def cycle_a_twisted_coordinates(self, u):
        return np.array([1, 0,0]) + (1/2+1/10)*np.array([-np.cos(u), 0, np.sin(u)])
    
    def cycle_a_twisted(self, axes):
        return ParametricFunction(
            lambda u: axes.c2p(*self.cycle_a_twisted_coordinates(u)),
            t_range=[0,TAU],
            color=PURE_RED
        ).set_shade_in_3d(True)
    def torus(self, axes):
        return Surface(
            lambda u, v: axes.c2p(*self.torus_coordinates(u, v)),
            u_range=[0, TAU],
            v_range=[0, TAU],
            fill_opacity=1,
            resolution=20,
        )
    
    def construct(self):
        axes = ThreeDAxes(x_range=[-4,4], x_length=8)
        
        torus = self.torus(axes)
        cycle_a_twisted = self.cycle_a_twisted(axes)
        
        self.set_camera_orientation(theta=-30 * DEGREES, phi=60 * DEGREES)
        self.camera.set_zoom(2)
        
        self.add(cycle_a_twisted,torus)
```

This yields the following image:
[image: Torus with set_shade_in_3d()]

As you can see part of the red path that should be in front of the torus is not being shaded correctly.

Comment: I think you've shifted it with (1/2 + 1/10)... the 1/10 is redundant?

Comment: I've increased the radius of the red circle from 1/2 to 1/2+1/10 so it would pop out from the small circle of the torus (which has radius 1/2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this will help - https://github.com/3b1b/manim/issues/1094

It seems like you may need two 2D wrapper curves **one** that is on the surface and the **other** that is behind, and increasing the granularity of the 2D behind the curve so that it will not pop up! I also did some digging and moving around the curve (2D), and the torus (3D but can be converted to 2D) will also resolve the issue, for which you need to save the torus into a 2D object and then use that (basically an image) to construct a single wrapper and shift it BEHIND
https://docs.manim.community/en/stable/tutorials/building_blocks.html#mobject-on-screen-order

Best of luck! Sorry, I tried but was not able to submit a working code in a short time.

Comment: Great, thank you! That indeed seems to do the trick. I'll update my post with the working version as soon as I find the time.

Answer (score 0):

set_shade_in_3d_true. this will calculate the depth of the curve with the torus...
i.e.

```
def cycle_a_twisted(self, t, axes):
    return ParametricFunction(
        lambda u: axes.c2p(*self.cycle_a_twisted_coordinates(u,t)),
        t_range=[0,TAU],
        color=PURE_RED
    ).set_shade_in_3d(true)
```

Then, if you want the curve to pop a little bit above the torus, add epsilon in the relevant direction to the curve coordinates

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This looks like the option I have been looking for, however it does no behave the way I would expect it to. More precisely, the part that should be in front of the torus is also hidden by the torus. Would you happen to know where that comes from? I'll edit the question to reflect this problem.

Comment: this I guess is the coordinates, which are the same as the torus. As I've written in the bottom, you probably want it to pop out from the torus not be tangential to the torus, so you'll probably have to scale it a little bit. or either you'll use a cylinder that is riding on top of the curve that has some volume - that way it will pop up naturally. That my guess haven't checked it though

Comment: Unless I am misunderstanding your point, I did try to lift it from the torus in the example I've added to the post. I've thought of using a surface instead, but the parametrization of such a surface becomes quite complicated, and will be very cumbersome in larger projects.

Comment: you're right. the problem is something of the renderring procedure, and not the coordinates. even if I'm rendering a sphere with the torus, it has the same problems...